# Why is this integral not invariant under change of variables? (differential entropy function / continuous entropy)

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, change-of-variable

Wikipedia states the following (can be found at the bottom of [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy#Properties_of_differential_entropy)):

> However, differential entropy does not have other desirable
> properties:
>
> It is **not invariant under change of variables**, and is therefore
> most useful with dimensionless variables.

Where differential entropy is as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy#Definition):

Let $X$ be a random variable with a probability density function $f$ whose support is a set $\mathbb{X}$. The differential entropy $h(X)$ is:

$$h(X) = -\int_{\mathbb{X}} f(x) \log f(x) dx$$

I would like to understand why it is not invariant under change of variables, but doesn't such a claim depend on $f$ and on the function used for the change of variables? I'm only familiar with the classic theorems (e.g. as in Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_variables#Integration)) which don't seem to produce such a general claim... Or is it that there's a simple way to demonstrates it wouldn't hold for a large class of functions?

Comment: In general, for arbitrary $f$, it's clearly not invariant under a change of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the statement is meant as "in general not" statement, but however:
One of the simplest transforms one could think of is to look at $Y:=2X$, which has pdf $f_Y(y) = \frac12 f_X(y/2)$. But the differential entropy of $Y$ is
\begin{align}
 \int_{2\mathbb X} f_Y(y)\log f_Y(y)\mathrm dy
 &= \int_{2\mathbb X} \frac12 f_X\left(\frac y2\right) \log\left(\frac12f_X\left(\frac y2\right)\right)\mathrm dy
\\&= \int_{\mathbb X}f_X(x)\left(\log\frac12+\log f_X(x)\right)\mathrm dx
\\&= \log \frac12 + \int_{\mathbb X}f_X(x)\log f_X(x)\mathrm dx.
\end{align}
As you see, just scaling already gives us an extra term of $\log\frac12$. As you see, the problem is the $\frac12$ appearing in the logarithm. This is remedied by the [Limiting density of discrete points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiting_density_of_discrete_points), where there is an additional probability density $m$ on $\mathbb X$ in the logarithm:
$$
  \int_{\mathbb X} f(x)\log\frac{f(x)}{m(x)} \mathrm dx.
$$

Comment: Great and sufficiently general example, thanks!